# MySQL Query Error between 2 dates

Tags: c#, mysql

I have an application working with mysql database.
Now i'm trying search some information in database to pass for a datagridview, but exist a error in query:

```
cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT (Sales.Doc) as 'Documento', (Sales.DocNo) as 'Nº Documento', (CustomerName) as 'Nome', (Sales.TotalIC) as 'Total IC', (TotalDesc) as 'Total Desconto', SubTotal as 'Sub Total', (GrandTotal) as 'Total', (InvoiceDate) as 'Data' from Sales,Customer where Sales.CustomerID=Customer.CustomerID and InvoiceDate between #'" + dtpInvoiceDateFrom.Text + "'# And #'" + dtpInvoiceDateTo.Text + "'# order by InvoiceDate desc", con);
```

Error: **MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1'**

Thanks for your time,
D3POD

Comment: What is the actual command? It's impossible for us to know what's inside your variables

Comment: Find out what the final string is - not the code - the string passed to the Command ctor. Then paste that into mysql workbench. Should be obvious where your problem is then. Oh and - sql injection - seriously.

Comment: I highly recommend using parameters instead of concatenating values into a SQL query.  Not only does it guard against sql injection, but it also help swith formatting issues.

Comment: These are strings, not dates. Use a parameterized query with real date-typed parameters. And google for `Bobby Tables`. If `dtpInvoiceDateTo` is a DateTimePicker the *date* is available through the `Value` property

Comment: Hi, thanks for all help.
I solved the error building a new query  with INNER JOIN.
now, the query is like this: "SELECT Doc, DocNo, InvoiceDate, Customer.CustomerName, TotalIC, TotalDesc, GrandTotal from Sales Inner JOIN Customer ON Sales.CustomerID = Customer.CustomerID WHERE InvoiceDate BETWEEN @date1 AND @date2"